# HTML Link that does POST (using Dojo)

Tags: javascript, html, post, dojo

I am new to web development so help is much appreciated!

I need to create a link in a form that will go to a separate window - the tricky part is that the link needs to be a POST request with arguments in this format (p_guid=55555555&f_name=someName&...) to a URL provided to me.

I'm using html + Dojo and have a link created:

HTML:

```
<a href="no-javascript.html" target="_blank" title="Identity Lookup Tool" id="${ns}identityLookupLink">Identity Lookup Tool</a>
```

In Dojo:

```
on(identityLookup, "click", function(evt) {
   console.log("Post will go here 1");
   // TODO
});
```

How can I get this pop up with a new window and do a post request to the URL?

Comment: Where do the parameters come from?

Comment: @EduardodeMatos - the parameters will come from the database, but I'm not too worried about those. I just wanna know how to stuff the values in somehow, even if I hardcode them for the time being just to figure out how to get this to behave the way I've described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try embedding your POST parameters in a hidden form.  Something like below.

```
<form id="myform" action="some_url_here" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="p_guid" value="55555555" />
    <input type="hidden" name="f_name" value="someName" />
</form>
```

Then when the link is clicked do something like:

```
dojo.byId("myform").submit();
```

This should submit the form against a new window because of the target="_blank" attribute on the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dojo/request`

```
on(identityLookup, "click", function(evt) {
    console.log("Post will go here 1");

    var request = require("dojo/request");
    var promise = request.post("url", {
        data: { "p_guid": 55555555, "f_name":"someName" },
        handleAs: "json"
    });
});
```